# Take user input for dynamic test cases in junit5

Tags: java, junit, junit5

I am not able to take user input data for dynamic test cases.

pom.xml

```
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.22.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <systemPropertyVariables>
                    <propertyName>link</propertyName>
                    <propertyName>buid</propertyName>
                    <propertyName>adminId</propertyName>
                    <propertyName>token</propertyName>
                </systemPropertyVariables>
                <useSystemClassLoader>false</useSystemClassLoader>
                <suiteXmlFiles>
                    <suiteXmlFile>./testng/MasterSuite.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                </suiteXmlFiles>
                <trimStackTrace>false</trimStackTrace>
                <!--<properties>
                    <property>
                        <name>reporter</name>
                        <value>
                            org.junit.jupiter.
                        </value>
                    </property>
                </properties>-->
                <argLine>
                    -javaagent:"${settings.localRepository}/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/${aspectj.version}/aspectjweaver-${aspectj.version}.jar"
                </argLine>
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                    <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
                    <version>1.9.5</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Test.java

```
System.setProperty("link", "val");
        System.setProperty("buid", "val1");
        System.setProperty("adminId", "val2");
        System.setProperty("token", "val3");
        log.info(System.getProperty("link"));
        log.info(System.getProperty("buid"));
        log.info(System.getProperty("adminId"));
        log.info(System.getProperty("token"));
```

So I have have used junit5 in my project to create dynamic test cases (with the help of @TestFactory) but I came with a problem of taking user input as just an entry point for my dynamic test cases.
Please suggest a way to achieve that, I also tried using @ParameterizedTests alongwith @TestFactory but sadly the @ParameterizedTest annotation is not supported with a @TestFactory method.
I also have tried to normally take input using Scanner class but that also doesnt work.
I expected to get the userinput data either from command line or simply pass the input data from a xml file as an parameter

Comment: It would be helpful if you provided a code snippet of the part of the code that expects user input. There might be several ways to achieve it depending on your implementation.

Comment: Personally, I'd just put the console based IO behind an abstraction and use a fake version of that abstraction for testing. But yes, show code and it'd be easier to understand your situation.

Comment: I have edited my question and added the code
can you please suggest me a way how can i configure the system property variables properly  @ODDminus1